# change page which is created for `\part`

Tags: formatting, parts

Is there a way to change the style of the heading etc. for `\part`?

I want to change the layout to leave out "Part 1." and instead just print out the part's name.

Actually I could change the question a bit:

I want instead of
"Part 1.
Title of part"

to have there
"semester 1"

and in the TOC it should say semester 1 as well instead of "I semester 1"

Comment: I want it to appear in the TOC. Changed the question, sorry. I think it's better to change how parts are displayed in the TOC and on these new pages at the beginning of a new part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a easy one assuming that you aren't bound to a `documentclass` (as you didn't mention any).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \addpart{One}

\end{document}
```